# Scrape only 1 result from google search via PHP

Tags: php, html, dom, web-scraping

Recently i've been having issues with the code of not parsing only 1 result from the google search url. Instead it parses 10 results which, I am not sure if it is changable.

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('https://www.google.com/search?q=raspberry&oq=raspberry&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.1144j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8');

$linkObjs = $html->find('div[class=jfp3ef] a');
foreach ($linkObjs as $linkObj) {
        $title = trim($linkObj->plaintext);
        $link = trim($linkObj->href);

        //if it is not a direct link but url reference found inside it, then extract
        if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link) && preg_match('/q=(.+)&amp;sa=/U', $link, $matches) && preg_match('/^https?/', $matches[1])) {
            $link = $matches[1];
        } else if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link)) { // skip if it is not a valid link
            continue;
        }

        echo '<p>Title:' . $title . '<br />';

        echo 'Link: ' . $link . '</p>';
}
?>
```

All, I need is 1 result being scraped off a google search. Thats all. The code i've included is the web scraper written in PHP.

Comment: Well don’t loop over `$linkObjs` then, but access only the first element in that array, and work with that …?

Comment: (That you should not scrape Google to begin with, is a different issue, but still … Don’t be surprised if they simply block your server IP at some point, or the “result” you get wants you to solve a CAPTCHA first, if you make requests like this regularly.)

Comment: do you maybe know the class id of the first element in array

Comment: I'm not sure if it's documented anywhere, but I just tried some things out and if you add `&num=1` to the querystring, you'll only get one result.

Comment: thanks @PatrickQ that seemed to be simplier done.